# How to display modified string?

Tags: ruby, string

I am creating a Daffy Duck speech converter (Very simple. Straight from CodeCademy) and I am having an issue with displaying the modified entry from the user.

Code:

```
puts "What would you like to convert to Daffy Duck language?"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
    print #{user_input}
else puts "I couldn't find any 's' in your entry. Please try again."
end
```

It will change any 's' in your entry to a 'th', therefore, making it sound like a Daffy Duck once read aloud. When I enter it into the interpreter, it will not display the modified string. It will just display the original entry by the user.

EDIT:
Thanks to the users below, the code is fixed, and I added a notice to the user with converted text. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

A `#` outside a string starts a [comment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/_lib/racc/rdoc/grammar_en_rdoc.html#label-Comments), so `#{user_input}` is ignored, i.e.

```
print #{user_input}
```

is equivalent to

```
print
```

You might wonder why a single `print` outputs the original input. This is because without arguments [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-print) will print `$_`. That's a [global variable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/doc/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+variables) which is set by [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets):

```
user_input = gets.chomp # assume we enter "foo"
user_input #=> "foo"
$_         #=> "foo\n"
```

Everything works as expected if you pass a string literal:

```
print "#{user_input}"
```

or simply

```
print user_input
```

Note that [`gsub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) returns `nil` if no substitutions were performed, so you can actually use it in your `if` statement:

```
if user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
  print user_input
else
  puts "I couldn't find any 's' in your entry. Please try again."
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add double quotes around the string interpolation. Otherwise your code was just returning the input.

```
puts "What would you like to convert to Daffy Duck language?"
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!

if user_input.include? "s"
  user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
  print "#{user_input}"
else 
 puts "I couldn't find any 's' in your entry. Please try again."
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need interpolation, actually. `print user_input` works. Notice how StackOverflow was even syntax highlighting your code as a comment. :)

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful!